# How do I make the position of a sprite off-center?

Tags: image, sprite, unity-game-engine

I am moving a 2D fireball animation along a path.  The fireball's animation comes from a sprite sheet similar to [this](http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-storyboard-of-fireball-206758396.jpg).  I want the fireball's position to be treated as the center of the head-part of the fireball, instead of being the center of the entire fireball.  How do I go about accomplishing this?  From what I've seen, it seems like I should be using pivots when I slice my sprite sheet, but I can't find a good tutorial on what pivots are and how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the image that your using in the project window.
2. In the options for the image make sure you select sprite sheet
3. Set the sprite mode to "Multiple"
4. Click on "Spite Editor"
5. Make sure that all the individual items are selected as different items

   1. Top left of the window "slice", click it
   2. In the little area that pops up click the slice button (automatic settings are usually good but if not you can change the location of each box manually if needed)
6. Select of the sliced sections (marked by boxes)
7. A little information area will appear in the bottom right (with things like name, position(this is were the box is in the image), size (how big the box is), etc.)
8. In the bottom of that box is a label called "pivot" by default it is set to "centre", change that to "Custom"
9. Now the "Custom Pivot" boxes will unlock allowing you to change the location of the pivot (the middle of were unity considers the image)
10. Press apply in the top bar near the right (once you have done this too all of the sprites, fireballs in your case)

[image: Visualisation of steps 7,8,9]

When you are then using any of the fire balls use the individual sprites that you have just created, Once your done then will be visible when you select the arrow on the right of the original image.

Sorry if I sound a bit condescending, I just wanted to make it very clear too anyone that reads this so there is no confusion. If you have any issues with this comment bellow.

Comment: Thank you for giving such detailed instructions.  That worked perfectly.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome glad i could help :)